# Finding Orthonormal Basis of a subspace spanned by $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find an orthonormal basis in the subspace $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by all solutions of $x+2y+3z-6j=0$. Then express vector $b = (1,1,1,1)$ to this basis.

I'm very confused on how to start this question. I know I would have to use
The Gram-Schmidt process but I'm not sure how.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First solve the equation parametrically, say: $x=-2y-3z+6j$. This shows the subspace of solutions is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^3$.

Then find a basis of the hyperplane, for instance:
$$u=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\;v=\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\;w=\begin{bmatrix}6\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}. $$

Apply Gram-Schmidt to find an orthogonal basis:
$$e_1=u,\quad e_2=v-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}\,u, \quad e_3=w-\frac{\langle u,w\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}\,u-\frac{\langle vu,w\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}\,v$$
(i.e. subtract from $v$ the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the line directed by u, and subtract from $w$ the projection of $w$ onto the subspace generated by $u$ and $v$).

Finally, normalise:
$$e'_1=\frac{e_1}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}, \quad e'_2=\frac{e_2}{\langle e_2,e_2\rangle}, \quad e'_3=\frac{e_3}{\langle e_3,e_3\rangle}.$$

Answer (score 0):

From x+ 2y+ 3z- 6j= 0 we have x= 6j- 3z- 2y.  So any vector in that subspace can be written as = <6j- 3z- 2y, y, z, j> = j<6, 0, 0, 1>- z<-3, 0, 1, 0>+ y<-2, 1, 0, 0>.  {<6, 0, 0, 1>, <-3, 0, 1, 0>, <-2, 1, 0, 0>} is a basis for that three dimensional vector space.

Using the Gran-Schmidt process, <6, 0, 0, 1> has length $\sqrt{7}$ and a unit vector in that direction is $\left<\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right>$.  Now, note that the dot product of that and <-3, 0, 1, 0> is $\frac{-18}{\sqrt{7}}$ so that $\frac{-18}{\sqrt{7}}\left<\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right>= \left<-\frac{108}{7}, 0, 0, -\frac{18}{7}\right>$ is its projection on $\left<\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right>$ and then $\left<-3, 0, 1, 0\right>- \left<\frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right>= \left<-3- \frac{6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}, 0\right>= \left<\frac{-3\sqrt{7}- 6}{\sqrt{7}}, 0, \frac{\sqrt{7}- 1}{\sqrt{7}}, 0\right>$ is perpendicular to it.  Divide that by its length to get a second unit vector perpendicular to the first.  Continue!

Answer (score 0):

You could circumvet part 2 if you chose $\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix}$ as your first basis vector.

i.e. A non-orthonormal basis is

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Then apply Graham-Schmidt.  Normalize the first vector

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix}$

Then take the inner product of the normalized first vector and the second vector

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12&\frac 12&\frac 12&\frac 12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = -1$

and

$\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} - (-1)\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac32\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix}$

and normalize it:

$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac 3{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\end{bmatrix}$

and finally
$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12&\frac 12&\frac 12&\frac 12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \frac 32,\begin{bmatrix}-\frac 3{\sqrt {12}}&\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}&\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}&\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \frac {3}{\sqrt 12}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} + \frac 32\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix} - \frac {3}{\sqrt12} \begin{bmatrix}-\frac 3{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\\\frac 1{\sqrt {12}}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

and normalize: $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\\\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\\0\end{bmatrix}$

And since we cheated part 2 is easy.

If that is too cheating... Suppose we start with

$\begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Now the first two vectors are already orthogonal, they just need to be normalized, and the last vector

$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \frac 15\begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} - \frac {3}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.6\\1.2\\-0.2\\0.4\end{bmatrix}$

I took a short cut.  Rather than normalizing the first two basis vectors, I divided the scalar by the square of the norm.

We still need to normalize though.

$\begin{bmatrix} -\frac {2}{\sqrt5}\\\frac 1{\sqrt 5}\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\\frac2{\sqrt 5}\\\frac1{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \frac {3}{5\sqrt2}\\\frac {6}{5\sqrt2}\\-\frac {1}{5\sqrt2}\\\frac {2}{5\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$

And now to find our $b$ in terms of this basis.

Take the inner product of $b$ with each vector and that is the weight in the new basis.

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -\frac {2}{\sqrt5}&0&\frac {3}{5\sqrt2}\\\frac 1{\sqrt 5}&0&\frac {6}{5\sqrt2}\\0&\frac{2}{\sqrt5}&-\frac{1}{5\sqrt 2}\\0&\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}&\frac {2}{5\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \frac {1}{\sqrt5}&\frac {3}{\sqrt5}&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need three vectors, perpendicular to $v=(1,2,3,-6)^t$, which are also mutually perpendicular.

Start with $(2,-1,0,0)^t$ ans $(0,0,6,3)^t$.  Now obviously the vector $(3,6,-1,2)^t$ matches the conditions.  Normalizing gives
$$\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}=\left\{\frac{\sqrt5}{5}\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
\frac{\sqrt5}{5}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix},
\frac{\sqrt2}{10}\begin{pmatrix}3\\6\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$
as an orthonormal basis.
Let $w=(1,1,1,1)^t$, then
$$w=\langle b_1,w\rangle b_1+\langle b_2,w\rangle b_2+
\langle b_3,w\rangle b_3.$$